# How to read BLOB data type using pyspark JDBC

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have RDS(oracle table) in aws and one of the column is in BLOB datatype

```
Table
Column Datatype
ID     varchar2
City   varchar2
File   BLOB
```

I'm tying to read the above table using pyspark JDBC, not seeing any records

```
df.printSchema()
root
|ID: String(nullable = true)
|City: String (nullable = true) 
|FILE: binary(nullable = true) 

df.show()
+---------+--------------+------------+
|ID       | CITY       | FILE       |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
+---------+--------------+-----------+
```

Currently I am using spark2.4.I would like to extract the binary datatype column values, what could be best approach ? I appreciate your response.

Comment: As I know, the JDBC ResultSet provides a getBlob method to get binary data.

You may refer to the following page:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getBlob(int)

Comment: Here,I'm using Apache spark with python to read the data from RDS.Is there any approach ?